# Add class to specific elements based on its content

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to add a specific class to a list item depending on its description. But when I add the script below, it adds it to all the list items, and not just those having that specific description.

List items with description "red" should get the class "red", list items with the description "blue" should get the class "blue".

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    if ($('.tax-desc:contains("red")')) {
        $(".taxonomy-list-item").addClass("red");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taxonomy-list-item">
  <div class="tax-details">
      <div class="tax-name">
          <div class="tax-title">
              <a href="#">Category 1</a>
          </div></div><div class="tax-desc">Red</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="taxonomy-list-item">
  <div class="tax-details">
      <div class="tax-name">
          <div class="tax-title">
              <a href="#">Category 2</a>
          </div></div><div class="tax-desc">Blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you think `$(".taxonomy-list-item").addClass("red");` does if it's not inside `if`? Why do you think the `if` would make it do anything different?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know, I have very limited JS knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an `if` statement. Use the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) selector to select the elements with this descendant.

`:contains()` is case-sensitive, so you need `Red` rather than `red` there.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.taxonomy-list-item:has(.tax-desc:contains("Red"))').addClass("red");
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taxonomy-list-item">
  <div class="tax-details">
    <div class="tax-name">
      <div class="tax-title">
        <a href="#">Category 1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tax-desc">Red</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="taxonomy-list-item">
  <div class="tax-details">
    <div class="tax-name">
      <div class="tax-title">
        <a href="#">Category 2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tax-desc">Blue</div>
  </div>
</div>
```